# New classes don't work, but old classes work perfectly fine

Tags: html, css

When I create a new class and try to use it, it does not work.
Here is the CSS I am using:

```
/* NEW */
.Test {
    color:purple;
}
/* OLD */
.TitleFont {
    font-family: MiriamLibre-Regular;
    color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 8em;
}
```

As you can see, the class commented NEW is one one I just created, and the one commented OLD is the one I had created a while ago.
I can use the new class with a h1 tag like this:

```
<h1 class="Test">This is a test.</h1>
```

When I go to the page it does not show the purple it was supposed to show. (It does the same for anything, I just put color:purple; as an example)

[Here is an image of it not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Agu.png)

I can replace the class used in the HTML with the old class like this:

```
<h1 class="TitleFont">This is a test.</h1>
```

And it works perfectly fine. (All my other classes from a while ago work fine too.)

[You can see it working here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl5k9.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox example?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Recreate it there or copy paste my code in there?

Comment: Yes, use something like codepen.io to give a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, you have this:

```
<h1 class="Test">
```

So the class you use there is `.test`

But your CSS rule looks like this:

```
.TestClass {
    color:purple;
}
```

That's for a class named `.TestClass` (which you don't use in your HTML code...)

Comment: Oops, writing error. Still doesn't work if I make it have the correct class.